# How do you get the latitude and longitude of the circumference of an arbitrary hemisphere?

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

I am attempting to draw the [three twilights and night](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/different-types-twilight.html) on an azimuthal equidistant projection. If the earth is divided by three planes perpendicular to the sub solar point. How would I find the lat and lon of the points along the circumferences to the resulting circles?

Comment: How exactly do you plan to "draw" it? Are you using software? Or do you want an explicit formula? I don't know how the projection would map those lines exactly, but at least, for a given point on the earth, we can find wich twilight it is or if it is day or night. The idea would be to consider it as a vector from the center of the Earth and then, all we have to do is measure the angle between the given point and the subsolar point

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulios I will be making the software that "draws" the projection. Mapping lat and lon onto the projection is fairly easy. I've already found the formulas for doing so. If I can find the lat/lon of the circles described here I can map them as well. Basically I am looking for the formula for the intersections of the planes and the sphere in a coordinate system that is useful to me.

Comment: I can see two ways to do that. First you can calulate the equation of the planes and then the intersection with the sphere. This is doable, but I think you will find it easier to convert the everything to cartesian coordinates and then calculate the angle between a given point and the subsolar point. This is done using the inner product and it much easier in cartesian. The twilight are basically defined by the angular altitude of the Sun

Comment: I assume your model of the Earth is a perfect sphere? If not, I am sorry, but I am not familiar with other datums

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulios Yes I was planning on assuming a perfect sphere. I'm not quite up to trying this with an oblate spheroid. On the bright side I think you've given me some good terms I can Google.

Answer (score 0):

Lets denote by $P:S^2\rightarrow D_1$ the azimuthal equidistant projection. Using geographic coordinates for the sphere $S^2$ and polar for the unit disc $D_1$ this is writen as 
$$P(\phi,\lambda)=\left(\frac{90-\phi}{180},\lambda\right)$$
The inverse is given by
$$P^{-1}(\rho,\theta)=(90-180\rho,\theta)$$
We will create a function $F:D_1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ wich will give for each point of the disc, the altitude of the sun. Then lets say, nautical twilight is between -6 and -12 degrees. We take the preimage $F^{-1}([-12,-6])$ wich gives the area on the azimuthal projection covered by nautical twilight. Or maybe just the boundary between civil and nautical twilight: $F^{-1}(\{-6\})$

To do that we start with a point on the disc in polar coordinates $x=(\rho, \theta)$, then $P^{-1}(x)=(\phi,\lambda)\in S^2$. Now we need to change coordinates from geographic to cartesian. This is done by
$$cart(\phi,\lambda)=(\cos\phi \cos\lambda, \cos\phi \sin\lambda,\sin\phi)$$

We also need the coordinates of the subsolar point in cartesian, let it be $s=(s_1,s_2,s_3)$. Then we calculate the angle between $cart(P^{-1}(x))$ and $s$, which since we use unit vectors is given by
$$arccos\left(\langle cart(P^{-1}(x)),s\rangle\right)$$
And the altitude of the sun at the point $p$ is given by
$$F(x)=90-arccos\left(\langle cart(P^{-1}(x)),s\rangle\right)$$